# Unable to update a user in SQLite3 with Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a view which is supposed to apply modification to a user.
This is my **view.py**:

```
@login_required
def edit_user_info(request):
    user = request.user
    print user.summary
    for key in request.POST:
        if key != "csrfmiddlewaretoken":
            user.__dict__[key] = request.POST.get(key, '')
    print user.summary
    user.save()
    print "saved"
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../home/')
```

The two prints show me that the field change correctly and that the user is saved correctly. But When I call the user back it's the old value that still present. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should certainly be using a ModelForm for this.

Comment: In fact since user is called from the request I just modify the user in the request instance not the one from the database I just needed to define: user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I should have done that:

```
@login_required
def edit_user_info(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    print user.summary
    for key in request.POST:
        if key != "csrfmiddlewaretoken":
            user.__dict__[key] = request.POST.get(key, '')
    print user.summary
    user.save()
    print "saved"
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../home/')
```